# Laravel Get Count of each User's latest Answer where Preferred = True

Tags: mysql, laravel, count, eloquent

I need to get the COUNT of each USER's most recent ANSWER where PREFERRED = TRUE. I have the query below, only problem is I don't know how to get it to filter by only user's most recent answer.

```
$countPreferred = Answer::where(
  'question_id', '=', $request->question_id)->select(
       DB::raw('DISTINCT(user_id)') 
  )->where('pref', '=', 1)->get()->count();
```

How can I filter this to only count each user's most recent answer where preferred = true ?

Comment: Please post the table schema, sample data and the desired outcome based on it

Comment: Can you please clarify if you want the COUNT of how many answers the user has submitted for this question, or if you want the most recent answer they provided. If you wanted the count of the most recent answer, wouldn't it end up being either 1 or 0 (1 if they have answered the question at all and 0 if they haven't answered yet).

Comment: Tables: http://i.imgur.com/zMRRG87.png

Ok to clarify, for each question, i want the COUNT of only most recent answers, where pref = 1.

The reason is, a user can submit an answer for a question several times. Pref = 1 just means they are in the preferrable range. I'm not interested in if their old answers were in the preferred range.  So I only want to count their most recent answer if pref = 1.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm still not quite grasping what it is you're trying to get. Can you give me specifics such as user 1 answered question 1 three times, question 2 once, and question 3 five times. Then show the output you want.

Comment: Ok lets say for Question 1:

2010 - User1 IS NOT in the preferred range
2009 - User1 IS in the preferred range

2011 - User 2 IS in the preferred range
2008 - User 2 IS NOT in the preferred range

2012 - User 3 IS in the preferred range
2011 - User 3 IS NOT in the preferred range

The desired result I want is 2.
Because User 2 and 3's most recent answer to the question, IS in the preferred range.

Hope that makes sense.
The end point is, I need that total count to find out the average of all user's recent answers that are in the preferred range. @BakerStreet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your last comment, I was able to construct the following data:

[image: Data]

Then, you just do the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(t1.pref)
FROM answers AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN answers AS t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
    AND t1.created_at < t2.created_at
WHERE t2.user_id IS NULL
```

You can either run this query as a [raw expression](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#raw-expressions), or you could Laravelize it... your choice. But that's the query you want.

If you want to do an audit on which answers are being selected for each user, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM answers AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN answers AS t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
    AND t1.created_at < t2.created_at
WHERE t2.user_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Hey @BakerStreet - that query was still counting older answers that were PREF = 1, when it shouldnt have because the most recent answer had PREF = 0.  

Good news, i think i figured out what I was looking for.  
  
$theCount = DB::select( DB::raw ("SELECT COUNT(distinct user_id)  
FROM answers  
WHERE PREF = 1  
ORDER BY id desc"));  
  
return $theCount;  
--------  
This is what it returns  
[{"COUNT(distinct user_id)":"3"}]  
Now the problem is it's returning as an array, how do I extract only get the value of 3 ? Thanks so much for the help

Comment: Actually, the query I provided above really is what you need, but your data may be a little different. You may be storing 0 instead of null in your pref column, which would then make the result count the 0. If that's the case, all you need to do is change the first line of the query to SUM (instead of count). I've gone ahead and changed my answer above to show what I'm talking about.

Comment: Awesome! I think that's it! Now time to laravelize it. Wow thanks for your help @BakerStreet you're the man

Comment: `$theCount = DB::select( DB::raw ("SELECT SUM(t1.pref)
FROM answers AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN answers AS t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
    AND t1.created_at < t2.created_at
WHERE t2.user_id IS NULL"));

return $theCount;` 
returns [{"SUM(t1.pref)":"2"}]  - how can I only extract the value of "2"